# Tailwind mx-auto does not center the element in the middle

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I know this quesion has been asked a lot of times. But they are all complex codes and the solutions differ based on their specific requirements.

Please run this very simple code on [Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/):

```
<div class="h-48 w-full bg-red-400">
  <a class="mx-auto inline-flex items-center bg-blue-400 px-8 py-5">Hello</a>
</div>
```

The `a` won't be placed in the middle. The `mx-auto` does not work.

Can someone please tell me why it is so? And what should I do to put it in the middle.

P.S. I can not use `text-center` on the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` to center an inline element. To center it without using `text-center` on the parent, consider applying `display: flex` instead of `display: inline-flex` by changing the `inline-flex` class to `flex` and then either:

Applying `justify-content: center` via `justify-center` to have the *Hello* text be centered:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="h-48 w-full bg-red-400">
  <a class="mx-auto flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-400 px-8 py-5">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Or `width: max-content` via `w-max` to have the `<a>` element itself be centered:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="h-48 w-full bg-red-400">
  <a class="mx-auto flex items-center w-max bg-blue-400 px-8 py-5">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that `w-max` is the main point here. That's the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The mx-auto class should work to center the  element horizontally within its parent . However, there is a common issue that might prevent it from working as expected: the parent element must have a defined width for mx-auto to center its child element.

In your code, the parent  has a class of h-48 w-full bg-red-400, but w-full makes it take up the full width of its parent container. To use mx-auto effectively for centering, you should remove w-full or specify a fixed width for the parent . Here's an updated version of your code with w-full removed:

```
<div class="h-48 bg-red-400">
 <a class="mx-auto inline-flex items-center bg-blue-400 px-8 py-5">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Now, the  element should be centered horizontally within the red . If you still encounter issues, please check if there are any conflicting CSS rules or styles that might be affecting the layout.